# How to correctly set the Independent Cities of Virginia in Open Street Map

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries

I would like to use the data from Open Street Map to identify which county I am in, but I noticed something unusual with the Independent Cities of Virginia. Essentially, there are a few cities that are independent of counties, even if they are completely contained within a county. When I do a query (Via the Map Quest Geocoding API), it returns that I am in the surrounding county, and not the city. For instance, here is Augusta County, which contains two independent cities, Staunton and Waynesboro. I've seen this for a half dozen other independent cities, BTW.

[image]

It's a bit tricky to see, but Staunton has a county boundary approximating the city boundaries. When I call Staunton, it correctly shows Staunton City as the county. When I look at Waynesboro, it stays it is in Augusta, not Waynesboro City. What I'm trying to do is to figure out how to make the appropriate correction. I can see a couple of possibilities, including:

1. Somehow trace an interior boundary that matches the city of Waynesboro, and identify that county as Waynesboro City.
2. Somehow make the existing Waynesboro think it's a county.

I'm not quite sure how either of those could be done, or which is the best, or even if there's a better solution all together. How can I make this correction?

Answer (score 1):

When looking at [Nominatim's internal representation for Waynesboro](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=97409595) you can see that there is an [administrative boundary for Waynesboro](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/206651) and also for [Augusta county](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/2534166), both having the same [admin_level](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aadmin_level). This might confuse Nominatim. One possibility might be to fix the relation for Augusta county by adding the relation for Waynesboro with the role *inner*. This excludes it from the relation (see [multipolygons](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation%3amultipolygon) for further explanations). I cannot say if this will fix the problem.

The [internal view of Staunton](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=97922932) seems to be correct as far as I can see. The important difference between the [Staunton relation](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/24316612) and the [Waynesboro relation](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/206651) seems to be the [border_type](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aborder_type). So I guess the correct solution is to fix the border_type for Waynesboros administrative border by setting it to the value *county*.

I strongly suggest to ask these kinds of questions on [help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/) in order to reach a much greater part of the community.